# Lining Labels with Radio buttons in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying out Bootstrap 4 form in which I would like to inline radio buttons with labels. I have it working with bootstrap 3 but I can't seem to work it out with bootstrap 4 and its custom-radio styling.

```
Desired Output:
Gender : ( ) Male ( )Female
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction.
Below is my approach

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group row col-lg-6">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-3 col-form-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-check row col-lg-6">
          <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Gender</label>
          <div class="col-9">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description">Male</span>
            </label>
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="mixed0" name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description">Female</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w7odmrtr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you `div` was not closed properly and second I just replaced `form-check` class with `form-group` an now it seems working.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group row col-lg-6">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-3 col-form-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row col-lg-6">
          <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Gender</label>
          <div class="col-9">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description">Male</span>
            </label>
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="mixed0" name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description">Female</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The missing div was a copy paste error. The form-group is working. Don't know where I have got the idea of styling as form-check

Comment: No probs happy to help, most of the time copy paste do things like that :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="firstName" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>  
          <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio"><span class="custom-control-description">Some Label</span></label>
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description" th:text="#{bool.true}">Yes</span>
            </label>
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="mixed0" name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description">No</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```